# Calculating & setting scroll speed of object in viewport

Tags: javascript

I have image I am scrolling within a div.
It make sure the image is visible I am using

```
var isVisible = (
    threshold.top >= -39 &&
    threshold.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
  );
```

What I am trying to do now is make sure that once the element is visible it is able to completely finish scrolling before going out of the view port.
I am thinking I can do this by effecting the speed value based on the the distance of the element from the top on the window. But I am having a very hard time doing this.

I am using .getBoundingClientRect() to get the distance the element is from the top of the viewport:

```
 var threshold =  document.getElementById('page-feature').getBoundingClientRect();
    var thresholdY = threshold.top;
```

Below is my code so far:

```
    function scrollImageInViewport() {
      var threshold =  document.getElementById('page-feature').getBoundingClientRect();
      var thresholdY = threshold.top;
      var isVisible = (
        threshold.top >= -39 &&
        threshold.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
      );

      if (isVisible && window.innerWidth > 550) {
        scrollDir(thresholdY);
      } 
    }

    function scrollUp(thresholdY) { 
      if (thresholdCounter < maxScrollNegative) {
          return;
      } else {
        pageScroll.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,' + (--thresholdCounter *speed) + 'px,0); -ms-transform:translate3d(0,' + (--thresholdCounter *speed) + 'px,0); transform:translate3d(0,' + (--thresholdCounter *speed) + 'px,0);'); 
      }  
    }; 

    function scrollDown(thresholdY) { 
      if (thresholdCounter > maxScrollPositive) {
          return;
      } else {
        pageScroll.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,' + (++thresholdCounter *speed) + 'px,0); -ms-transform:translate3d(0,' + (++thresholdCounter *speed) + 'px,0); transform:translate3d(0,' + (++thresholdCounter *speed) + 'px,0);');  
      }   
    }; 

    function scrollToTop(){
      initScroll();
      pageScroll.setAttribute('style', 'transform:translate3d(0,0,0);'); 
      thresholdCounter = 0;
    };


    function scrollDir(thresholdY) {
      var scroll = window.scrollY;
      if(scroll > position) {
        distanceFromTop(thresholdY);
        scrollUp(thresholdY);
      } else if (scroll < position ){
        scrollDown(thresholdY);
      }
      position = scroll;
    };

    function distanceFromTop(thresholdY) {
        if (thresholdY > 0) {
 `enter code here`//set speed as distance from top /px of not shown content 
          speed = (scrollImageHeight - scrollVisibleHeight) / thresholdY;
        }

    };

    function initScroll(){
      position = window.scrollY;
      pageScroll = document.getElementById('page-scroll'); 
      scrollImageHeight = pageScroll.offsetHeight; //total height of scroll image
      pagePanel =  document.getElementById("pagePanel");
      pageStyle = window.getComputedStyle(pagePanel,"");
      size = pageStyle.getPropertyValue("height");
      scrollVisibleHeight = parseInt(size, 10);//visible height of scroll image
      scrollImageEnd = scrollImageHeight - scrollVisibleHeight;
      maxScrollNegative = -scrollImageEnd / speed;
    }

    var speed; 
    var thresholdCounter = 0; 
    var maxScrollPositive = 0;
    var position, 
      pageScroll, 
      scrollImageHeight, 
      pagePanel, 
      pageStyle, 
      size, 
      scrollVisibleHeight, 
      scrollImageEnd,
      maxScrollNegative;

    window.addEventListener('resize', scrollToTop);
    document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollImageInViewport);
    window.addEventListener('load', initScroll);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with:

```
var featurePage =  document.getElementById('page-feature')
var pageScroll = document.getElementById('page-scroll'); 

var startP, // where animation needs to begin
  endP, // where animation needs to end
  diff; // visible element size

function getElementOffset(){ //init
    var de = document.documentElement;
    var box = featurePage.getBoundingClientRect();
    var top = box.top + window.pageYOffset - de.clientTop;
    var bottom = box.bottom + window.pageYOffset - de.clientTop;
    var winHight = window.innerHeight; 

    diff = bottom - top;
    var elPadding = (winHight - diff);

    startP = top - elPadding;
    endP = bottom - elPadding;

    scrollImage()
}

function scrollImage(){
  var scrollImageHeight = pageScroll.offsetHeight;
  var scrollPos = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
  var s1 = scrollPos - startP;
  var realPos = -s1/diff;
  var lengthLeft = scrollImageHeight - (diff)  
  if ( realPos < 0.09 && realPos > -1){
    pageScroll.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,' + (realPos * lengthLeft) + 'px,0); -ms-transform:translate3d(0,' + (realPos *lengthLeft) + 'px,0); transform:translate3d(0,' + (realPos *lengthLeft) + 'px,0);'); 
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', getElementOffset);
document.addEventListener('scroll', getElementOffset);
```